# WPF - Nested ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, scrollviewer

As shown in the below  image I have few input fields and a DataGrid in a WPF Window.
All controls are placed inside a ScrollViewer.

[image]

Example Code:

```
<Window>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Label/>
                <TextBox/>
                <Label/>
                <TextBox/>
                <Label/>
                <TextBox/>
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

**Requirement**

1) The `Datagrid` should occupy all the available space in window.

2) I Want to show the `ScrollViewer` only if there is no room enough to accommodate Input fields.
[image]

3) I want to show the `DataGrid` `ScrollViewer` only if there is enough space to accommodate all the input filed in window but no enough space to accommodate all the columns/rows in `DataGrid`.
[image]

4) I want to show both `ScrollViewer`s if there is no enough space to accommodate input fields and thecolumns/rows in datagrid.

[image]

I have tried many possible ways, But i was unable to enable `ScrollViewer` in `DataGrid`. Could any one please help me to overcome this issue.
Providing sample XAML code will  be highly appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly adding datagrid to your main grid.Enclose your Datagrid with scrollviewer and a grid.Give that grid the size of your datagrid.
Example:-

```
    <Window>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Label/>
                <TextBox/>
                <Label/>
                <TextBox/>
                <Label/>
                <TextBox/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
              <ScrollViewer>
                 <DataGrid/>
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: @Beson I dont want to enclose Datagrid with scrollviewer., i need to activate DataGrid's builin scrollbars instead.